# how to regex character < and > replace like &lt; and &gt; in tag <code> </code>?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string like bellow:

```
<pre title="language-markup">
    <code>
        <div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody">
            abc
        </div>
    </code>
</pre>
```

In the `<code></code>` tag I want to replace all the characters `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. How should I do?

Example: `<code> &lt; div &gt;<code>`.

Please tell me if you have any ideas. Thanks all.

Comment: give `htmlspecialchars()` a try, this escapes most special characters

Comment: if i use htmlentities, it change all character < like &lt; and > like &gt; , i want in tag <code> anything in here have <  be change &lt; and > change &gt; </code>

Comment: ehm dont apply it to the whole code then, just in the `<code>` Tags...

Comment: i don't understand, i have a string <pre title="language-markup">
    <code>
        <div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody">
            abc
        </div>
    </code>
</pre>

Comment: I want to replace all character <  and > in tag <code> like &lt; and &gt;

Comment: look at Hanky Panky's updated answer, it should tell you what to do

Comment: Hi lino, i look at Hanky Panky's  answer, but it's change all character like < , it not my mean, i have a string like: <pre title="language-markup"> <code> <div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody"> abc </div> </code> </pre>  and i want replace all < inside <code></code>

Comment: so you mean something like &lt;code&gt; &lt;/code&gt; or what? else im sorry, i dont know what your problem is then

Comment: no problem Lino. Thanks for help, i'm so grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below solution:

```
$textToScan = '<pre title="language-markup">
    <code>
        <div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody">
            abc
        </div>
    </code>
</pre>';


// the regex pattern (case insensitive & multiline
$search = "~<code>(.*?)</code>~is";

// first look for all CODE tags and their content
preg_match_all($search, $textToScan, $matches);
//print_r($matches);

// now replace all the CODE tags and their content with a htmlspecialchars() content
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    $replace = htmlspecialchars($match);
    // now replace the previously found CODE block
    $textToScan = str_replace($match, $replace, $textToScan);
}

// output result
echo $textToScan;
```

output:

```
<pre title="language-markup">
    <code>
        &lt;div title=&quot;item_content item_view_content&quot; itemprop=&quot;articleBody&quot;&gt;
            abc
        &lt;/div&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: the variable $matches not declare?

Comment: no need to declare `$matches` as it is third parameter of `preg_match_all` function, for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: it work, but like this, it not my result i want <div class="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody"><br />     {if isset($bBlogView)}<br /> &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;<br />    $Behavior.checkhtml = function()<br />    {l}<br />          var htmlToLoad=&#039;{$aItem.text}&#039;;<br />          htmlToLoad = htmlToLoad.replace(/&lt;br &#92;/&gt;/g,&#039;&#92;n&#039;);<br />          $(&#039;#ch&#039;).html(htmlToLoad);<br />          Prism.highlightAll();<br />    {r};<br />&lt;/script&gt;

Comment: what is your current string?

Comment: <pre title="language-markup"> <code> <div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody"> abc </div> </code> </pre>

Comment: output for this code is
<pre title="language-markup"> <code> &lt;div title=&quot;item_content item_view_content&quot; itemprop=&quot;articleBody&quot;&gt; abc &lt;/div&gt; </code> </pre>

Comment: Hi Chenta Ameta, i want to replace all character < and > inside <code> <code> like &lt; and &gt;  .

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). That is there only to serve that very purpose

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>");
```

[Output](https://eval.in/485290) of your HTML code

```
&lt;pre title=&quot;language-markup&quot;&gt;&lt;code&gt;
&lt;div title=&quot;item_content item_view_content&quot; 
itemprop=&quot;articleBody&quot;&gt;abc&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;
```

Another example based on your comment

```
<code>
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars('html here');?>
</code>
```

Comment: if i use htmlentities, it change all character < like &lt; and > like &gt; , i want in tag <code> anything in here have <  be change &lt; and > change &gt; </code>

Comment: Then apply it only to the html that goes inside your `<code>` tag

Comment: I mean <code></code> is a string not a html tag, and i want to replace all character < and > in <code></code> like &lt and &gt;

Comment: It's a string that you have made, isnt it?

Comment: Hi Hanky Panky, actually

Comment: So when you have created that string you can run only that string through htmlspecialchars and nothing else. Wrong?

Comment: if i use htmlspecialchars it replace all < like &lt; , it not my mean, i want to replace all < inside <code></code> in the string

Answer (score 1):

Use either `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`

```
$string = "<html></html>"

// Do this
$encodedString = htmlentities($string);
// or
$encodedString = htmlspecialchars($string);
```

The difference in these two functions is that one will encode everything or better said "entities". The other will only encode special characters.

Below are some quotes from PHP.net

#### From the PHP documentation for htmlentities:

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

#### From the PHP documentation for htmlspecialchars:

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming. If you require all HTML character entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.

Comment: if i use htmlentities, it change all character < like &lt; and > like &gt; , i want in tag <code> anything in here have <  be change &lt; and > change &gt; </code>

Comment: @XuânHiểnNgô `htmlspecialchars()` is the function for you then.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm trying to fix my problem. I was successed, this is my code to resolve my problem. You can use my way or use Chetan Ameta's way bellow my answer:

```
function replaceString($string)
{
    preg_match_all('/<code>(.*?)<\/code>/', $string, $matches);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
        $result[$key] = str_replace(['<', '>'], ['&lt;', '&gt;'], $match);
    }
    return str_replace($matches[1], $result, $string);
}

$string = '<pre title="language-markup"><code><div title="item_content item_view_content" itemprop="articleBody">abc</div></code></pre>';
echo replaceString($string);
```

I like this place, thanks all help me, i'm so grateful. Thank again.